# is it possible for a css sqaure/rectangle to have the right side to look like a triangle right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if its able to have a square that has a point on the right side of it something like this in just one css:

http://prntscr.com/59wn94

I tried to make one just by using one div I wasn't able to manipulate enough its much easier for when creating a square then just add up a triangle right to it. but I want something that is on just on css like a combination of square and triangle-right.

Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/wbZet/1311/ . I just improvised some fiddle to create this stuff.

```
<div id="nav">
    <a>PLAY</a>
</div>
<div id="triangle-up" />

#triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 35px solid red;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;    
    float: left;
}
#nav {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    height:50px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background: red;
}
#nav a {
    margin: 25px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Pseudo-elements - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
div{
  position: relative;/*it important to set this to relative to be able to use :before in absolute*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red
}

div:before{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid red

}
```

```html
<div>Play</div>
```

Comment: I have a follow up question is it possible that the :before is also as part of the div because the div is an anchor so when i selected the :before div it is not part of the anchor... @tambo