# rectangle with right hand side triangle outline only

Tags: css

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120526/is-it-possible-for-a-css-sqaure-rectangle-to-have-the-right-side-to-look-like-a) following css code to create rectangle plus right hand side triangle

```css
div{
  position: relative;/*it important to set this to relative to be able to use :before in absolute*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red
}

div:before{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid red

}
```

```html
<div>Play</div>
```

how should I do the same thing, but only with the outline ?

sample image would be like bellow(number 2 box): [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play around with `:after` positioned over `:before` to create border.

```css
div{
  position: relative;/*it important to set this to relative to be able to use :before in absolute*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div:before{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 21px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left: 21px solid red

}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: -2px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid white;

}
```

```html
<div>Play</div>
```